strange matplotlib limits when aspect ratio is fixed
Im facing a strange behaviour from matplotlib when equal aspect ratio is preserved.
For starters, this is the minimum code sample to show this behaviour. First with the correct behaviour and second with the crooked behaviour
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.random.randn(len(x))

# Create a plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
# Set x-axis limits
ax.set_xlim(2, 5)

# Print the x and y limits
print(f"x-axis limits before plotting: {ax.get_xlim()}")
print(f"y-axis limits before plotting: {ax.get_ylim()}")

ax.plot(x, y*10)


# Print the x and y limits
print(f"x-axis limits after plotting: {ax.get_xlim()}")
print(f"y-axis limits after plotting: {ax.get_ylim()}")

# Set x-axis limits
ax.set_xlim(2, 5)

# Print the x and y limits
print(f"x-axis limits after setting xlim: {ax.get_xlim()}")
print(f"y-axis limits after setting xlim: {ax.get_ylim()}")

# Show the plot
plt.show()

So this prints
x-axis limits before plotting: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits before plotting: (0.0, 1.0)
x-axis limits after plotting: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits after plotting: (-23.30742047433786, 21.093948480431905)
x-axis limits after setting xlim: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits after setting xlim: (-23.30742047433786, 21.093948480431905)

which correctly correspond to the plot being generated

Now the strange thing happens when I uncomment the ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim') line.
It prints below data
x-axis limits before plotting: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits before plotting: (0.0, 1.0)
x-axis limits after plotting: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits after plotting: (-31.012258207723225, 22.633044899779353)
x-axis limits after setting xlim: (2.0, 5.0)
y-axis limits after setting xlim: (-31.012258207723225, 22.633044899779353)

But shows a graph with completely different limits

My questions are:

is there anyway to get matplotlib to return the correct x,y limits
is there anyway to keep AR by changing only y data limits keeping manually set xlimits untouched ?

EDIT:
@jodyKlymac pointed out fig.draw_without_rendering() to be used to get the correct limits. so this works.
But after plotting, I tried changing the xlim on line number 28. Matplotlib ignores this set_xlim. why and how to fix this. I want to see the final image with x limits going from 2 to 5. Doesn't matter how cropped the y axis is but cannot use adjustable='box' because I need the plotting bbox large enough

It's not clear what results you were expecting.  You have data with about 5 times as much Y range as X range; if you insist on 1:1 aspect ratio, then either there's wasted space to the sides, there's Y-axis clipping, or the plot is 5 times as tall as it is wide.

The "correct" xy limits are returned after a draw, so do fig.draw_without_rendering().  Otherwise I agree it is hard to understand what you want the plot to look like.

@jasonharper -- The issue I have is what I get from get_xlim() and get_ylim() is incorrect. Matplotlib chooses different limits as shown in the plots but giving wrong information

@JodyKlymak, am I correct to say you suggest is to run draw_without_rendering() before getting the xlim, ylim ?

Hi @JodyKlymak , Thanks for the correct suggestion-- what you said worked to get the correct axis limits. but after the plot, I am unable to set the xlim as per my edited question. Any suggestion for that ?

When you set the aspect ratio to 'equal', 'datalim', matplotlib will create a graph such that a line segment that goes along the y-axis one unit will be the same size as a line segment that goes along the x-axis one unit. Being that the range of values along the y-axis is ~10x the range of values along the x-axis, it is expected for the chart to look as it does.
If you really wanted to keep the aspect ratio, you could potentially adjust the figure size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 20))

This would remove the extra white space on the left and right of the graph. You would adjust the size such that it scales similarly to the limits (minimum/maximum values) of your dataset.
